# How can I use arrays in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying this in 16.04 but it is not working. Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8880633/2771043.

Edit: Apparently this works if you copy and past it to a terminal but not on a script file. How do I get it to work the same way on a .sh file?

```
declare -a arr=("element1" "element2" "element3")

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$i"
done
```

I get

```
old.sh: 2: old.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

If I take out the brackets, I get

```
old.sh: 2: old.sh: declare: not found
old.sh: 5: old.sh: Bad substitution
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into a terminal window, and it works correctly for me (in my installed and up to date 16.04). The output is a list with three lines (with one 'element' on each line). I use the default shell intepreter in the terminal window. Have you modified your terminal window to run some other shell interpreter (not bash)?

Comment: I haven't modified anything, are you on 16.04 though? Apparently it works on earlier versions. edit: I did as you did and it works... but how do I make it work on a script???

Comment: Yes: `lsb_release -a` --> `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS` ; uname -a`--> ` Linux xenial32 4.4.0-77-generic #98-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 26 08:33:44 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux` ; `apt-cache policy bash` --> `Installerad: 4.3-14ubuntu1.1`

Comment: I can try to make it work in a script ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works if you add the crunchbang line at the head end of the script to force the shell interpreter to use the `bash` syntax, and not default to the old `sh` syntax. (It works for me also without the crunchbang line, but for many reasons it is a good idea to use a crunchbang line.)

I created the file `arraytest`.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=("element1" "element2" "element3")

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$i"
done
```

Then I made it executable and executed it.

```
chmod ugo+x arraytest

$ ./arraytest
element1
element2
element3
```